# Chart.js does not get the updated value from Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

Working on a project here where I take values from an API, using Flask. And then adding it to a chart using chart.js

I got it to work somewhat, issue I am having is that the variable I use to add the value to the chart with, but it does not change the variable, I add to the chart, whenever the value changes in the API.

Meaning:
Sell Price: 10.3
*sell price change to 10.4*
Sell Price: 10.3 <-- It does not change to 10.4

Here is my python code for it:

```
@app.route('/product/<product>')
def productPage(product):
    price = []
    data = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=').json()
    sell = data['products'][product]['sell_summary']
    for x in sell:
        price.append(x['pricePerUnit'])
    currentSell = data['products'][product]['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
    return render_template('product.html', product=product, price=price, currentSell=currentSell)


@app.route('/graph_update/<product>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def graph_update(product):
    data = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=').json()
    currentSell = data['products'][product]['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
    return jsonify('', render_template('graph_update.html', currentSell=currentSell))
```

And here HTML/JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="position: relative; height: 40vh; width: 80vw">
  <canvas style="width: 25%" id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<input
  type="button"
  value="add data"
  style="margin-top: 25%"
  onclick="addData()"
/>
<h1 style="padding-top: 25%">{{product}}</h1>
{% for sell in price %}
<p id="sellprice">{{ sell }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script>
  var sellprice = JSON.parse("{{ currentSell | tojson | safe }}");
  var product = "{{ product }}";
  let myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
  let priceChart = new Chart(myChart, {
    type: "line", // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
    data: {
      labels: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Sell Price",
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {},
  });

  var getData = function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/graph_update/" + product,
      success: function (data) {
        // process your data to pull out what you plan to use to update the chart
        // e.g. new label and a new data point

        // add new label and data point to chart's underlying data structures
        var sellprice = JSON.parse("{{ currentSell | tojson | safe }}");
        priceChart.data.labels.push(sellprice);
        priceChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(sellprice);

        // re-render the chart
        priceChart.update();
      },
    });
  };

  // get new data every 3 seconds
  setInterval(getData, 10000);
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your python code at the endpoint `/graph_update/<product>` should return data as JSON and currently it is doing the following:

```
 return jsonify('', render_template('graph_update.html', currentSell=currentSell))
```

You need to return something like

```
return jsonify(data) # or subset of data that you need to pass
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222755/discussion-on-answer-by-balderman-chart-js-does-not-get-the-updated-value-from-f).